# I have two tables in the same Sheet. How do I align rows which have the same set of data using Excel or VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have two tables in the same Excel Sheet.

I want to use an Excel VBA code in order to align a set of rows that are partly equal on the same line. Is it possible to do this?

I've been thinking about this but I can't seem to figure out the code.

For example, I want to align the rows with the same 
"Number", "Name", and "Order" inputted.

Before:

[image]

After:
[image]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm not understanding how the data afterwards is sorted. It looks like it's sorted based on table1's "Number" column, but why is there a gap in row 5?

Comment: Sorry about that. I didn't consider much about the sorting aspect when I created the sample image. Basically the "After" image is what we have been doing manually. The sorting didn't matter much. We just insert an extra line for rows that is not equal on the other table to show that this item does not exist in the new table.

Comment: That's okay I was just thinking that matching these up is probably simpler when they're sorted which I didn't really convey

Answer (score 1):

Might not be the best way, but a relatively simple way might be to just automate what you're doing manually. Loop through the rows, check if the columns you want are the same, the use the `Range.Insert` method to perform the inserts instead of doing them manually.

If this were a pair of tables in SQL, what you're looking for is the equivalent of a `FULL OUTER JOIN` of the two tables on the three columns of interest. There's some information about performing this type of operation in Excel over in [this Super User question](https://superuser.com/questions/1023123/how-to-simulate-a-full-outer-join-in-excel).

I threw the sample data into a SQL database and was able to reproduce the desired output using these queries:

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM Table1 t1
    FULL OUTER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.Number = t2.Number AND t1.[Name] = t2.[Name] AND t1.[Order] = t2.[Order]
ORDER BY CASE WHEN t1.Number IS NULL THEN t2.Number ELSE t1.Number END

SELECT t2.* 
FROM Table1 t1
    FULL OUTER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.Number = t2.Number AND t1.[Name] = t2.[Name] AND t1.[Order] = t2.[Order]
ORDER BY CASE WHEN t1.Number IS NULL THEN t2.Number ELSE t1.Number END
```